# TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'Redditor' objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, praw

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 56, in <module>
    run(r, comments_replied_to)
  File "run.py", line 30, in run_bot
    b.write("Author=" + comment.submission.author + "\n")
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'Redditor' objects
```

This is the traceback recieved from the code, I'm not sure how to fix this, thank you.

Here's the code

```
with open ("first.txt", "a") as f, open 
    ("second.txt", "a") as b:
        f.write(comment.id + "\n")
            b.write("author=" + comment.submission.author + "\n")
```

Comment: Please provide some examples of the original code which this error is in reference to.

Comment: You cannot concat strings and objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you're using PRAW and want to get the reddit username? Right now, you're trying to concatenate a String with the Redditor object.

Instead, you need to use `Redditor.name` to access the username. Have a look at the docs for the [`Redditor`](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/redditor.html) object.

In your case that would be

```
comment.submission.author.name
```

Comment: I'm looking for the script to write the submitter (of the post not comment's) username in that text file. First.txt works well, second.txt gives the error.

Comment: That absolutely solved the issue, thank you. I didn't know that my use of comment.submission.author was creating the error.

Comment: That definitely makes sense, a second look at https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/comment.html helps.